# Overloading stresses wooden planks beyond their elastic range, causing them to fail?

Tags: material-science

info:

In a video on youtube in an unsafe way a car is boarding a ship going over two wooden planks. It looks to me that there two 2x10" wooden boards support a 5,000 lbs car/truck (a not so light load). The video shows that there is the fact that a car (a not so light load) can board a ship successfully going over those two wooden planks. In that way the following link is direct proof that it is possible.

See:

[image: Car to board ship going over a plank]

But also: Some people have criticised the authenticity of the video, suggesting the video might have been faked or digitally edited. So, I have a question.

question:

If it is wood they used so that it depends on the wood, including the length, the grain, how dry it is. Is it possible and is there a way of telling somthing about it in general?

Comment: Looks that way in the video. Also, yes/no questions tend to be a bad fit for this site because the single word answer is not long enough to submit as an answer.

Comment: Seriously - that depends on the wood. Including the length. The grain. How dry it is. It is certainly possible - but there is no way of telling in general. A better question would be "what is the maximum stress in a wooden board of dimensions x*y*z, loaded with weight W in the middle"? Then you can see...

Comment: I really don't understand the question, when your own link is direct proof that it *is* possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer the question that it would have made sense to ask:

> If I have a beam of dimensions w*h*l, supported at the ends and loaded with weight W, what is the maximum tensile stress?

There are handy websites that help you answer this - my favorite is engineeringtoolbox.com . Note - *engineering* toolbox. This is only borderline physics.

From http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/beam-stress-deflection-d_1312.html

$$\sigma = \frac{yF\ell}{4I}$$

Where $\sigma$ is the stress, $y$ is the perpendicular distance to the "neutral" axis, $\ell$ is the length, and $I$ is the second moment of area.  For a beam of uniform section $w\times h$ we know the second moment of area $I=\frac{1}{12}w\cdot h^3$, and $y = h/2$. Thus we can write the stress as

$$\sigma = \frac{hF\ell}{2\cdot 4 \cdot \frac{1}{12} w \cdot h^3} = \frac{3F\ell}{2 w \cdot h^2}$$

Putting in reasonable dimensions for your board:

$$h = 0.05 m\\
w = 0.25 m\\
\ell = 2 m\\
F = 25 kN$$

Then we find

$$\sigma = 120 MPa$$

According to http://www.conradfp.com/pdf/ch4-Mechanical-Properties-of-Wood.pdf , the "modulus of rupture" of most woods under static load is around 80 MPa. But the number varies tremendously - depending on the type of wood, and the moisture content.

From this I conclude that you can drive a 5000 pound truck over a short plank - but a long plank will fail.

Note that since the truck's wheels spread the load, you don't have the "all load in the middle" scenario. For a uniformly distributed load, you gain a factor 2x (see same link above). This is why the truck in the video is able to "just" do it. But I have to admit, based on the above calculation they took a risk...